# Can we have format specifiers in HTML code?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

Can we have format specifiers in HTML code placed in the app bundle?

Once the response from server comes back, parse the HTML, place the real values in the place of format specifiers and load it on a `UIWebView`.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Interesting question. You might want to include a tiny bit of background as to why you need to do this with `UIWebView` and not a more "native" solution.

Comment: What do you mean with *format specifiers*?

Comment: @esqew - I should show the values in a tabular column format. I thought it would be easy to create a tabular column in HTML and load it in a webview if I can insert the values into HTML in the desire columns in Table.

Comment: yes, you can store _templates_ in the bundle.

Comment: @Eonil - I meant %@ instead of replaceable string, %d instead of integer value.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible at all as you describe it (similar to `NSString`'s `stringWithFormat:`). A workaround would be to load the content of the HTML file into an `NSMutableString` and then use replacement functions like [`replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:).

Comment: The values would be different, I can't just replace the occurrence.

Comment: That's why you'd use unique placeholders that would never appear anywhere else in your code instead of generalized placeholders like `%@` or `%d`. If your data is of an indeterminate length, my workaround unfortunately won't help.

Comment: @holex - Is there any tutorial available to see how its done, or have you done it before? Can you help me out.

Comment: Another (and probably the most realistic) way would be to get the content from the server with the variables already in it.

Comment: Please post some template and actual data samples.

Comment: @Fr33KiLL, that'd be simple, like your template has `...<b><!--NAME--><b>...`, and after you loaded the template file and you have the _name_ you can replace `<!--NAME-->` with the actual _name_ you received from your server. the idea is this, the actual implementation for having the best performance does depend on your current task.

Comment: @holex Hmm, let me try out and let you know.